# Lettuce core redis blpop brings Type mismatch Can't assign non-array value to an array

Tags: redis

I am using Letuce core .The following code ((4) point) brings error
:"Type mismatch Can't assign non-array value to an array"

```
    redisListCommands.lpush("service:queue","test1");
    redisListCommands.lpush("service:queue","test2");
    redisListCommands.lpush("service:queue","test3");
    redisListCommands.brpop(123,"service:queue"); // (4)
```

Comment: It works for me. Lettuce `5.0.3`, Redis `4.0.9`.

Comment: In what environment do you run it? Note, that second argument is vararg, an implicit array of 1 element. That looks related  to the error you see.

Comment: Yes now it works,for me too.And can you say when I set Long.MAX_VALUE instead of timeout ,it doesnt work,but in case of any other number it works?
I want blocking take,without timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
redisListCommands.brpop(123, (Object[]) new String[]{"service:queue"});
```

but your initial code works fine for me.

Comment: I don't know, something about your environment setup. I just used explicit array creation instead of implicit.

Comment: ok. And can you say when I set Long.MAX_VALUE instead of timeout ,it doesnt work,but in case of any other number it works?
I want blocking take,without timeout.

Comment: `0` means no timeout. `Long.MAX_VALUE` is too much, it takes integer.

Comment: I set timeout 0(without timeout),but were appeard cases that result of brpop brings follwing exception: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out at io.lettuce.core.LettuceFutures.awaitOrCancel(LettuceFutures.java:114) at io.lettuce.core.FutureSyncInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FutureSyncInvocationHandler.java:62) at io.lettuce.core.internal.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:80) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.brpop(Unknown Source) :

What timeoutexception,when I set 0:

Comment: A few minutes (2-3);

Comment: There is a command level timeout and connection level. To set the latter use: `RedisURI.builder().withTimeout(Duration.ofDays(10000)).build();`